# Assembly shift left logic from single bit to hex pattern

Tags: assembly, logic, mips, shift

How would I use sll to turn a single 1 bit pattern to a hex pattern?

For example, in one register we have a `1` and by using sll I should be able to get `0xAAAAAAAA`.

Using an online converter, I found that `OxAAAAAAAA` is `2863311530`, and from there that number is

```
1101 0010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010
```

So how does shift left logic create that new pattern ? I'm new to assembly and trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: What do you mean by *"shift left logic"*? If you mean shifting bits left how does that relate to converting from decimal to hex to binary in your quesiton?

Comment: I don't quite see the point, but you'd have to bitwise-or the parts together, e.g.  `(1<<1)|(1<<3)|(1<<5)...`

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. This is what Im given : ori $t0,$0,0x01 from there I need to use sll,and,nor,or,xor to turn that single bit to 0xAAAAAAAA. I thought by converting the hex to decimal and from decimal to binary would help in getting the new pattern. Im new to this so i understand sll but I still do not under stand what bit wise-or actually does or how that would help me get the single bit 1 to that hex pattern.

Comment: You are going to want to check the bitmap pattern for 0xAAAAAAAA, it should be: `10101010101010101010101010101010`.  If t0 contains 1 and you shift it left by 1, it will contain 10.  If you shift it left by another 1 (for a total of 2), it would contain 100.  If you take that 100 and `or` it with 1, you will get 101.  If you shift that left by 2 more, you'll get 10100, which you can then `or` with 1, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer you literally blew my mind it makes so much f***** sense right now. Thanks to all who answered I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There are going to be other ways to get there (there always are), but that should get you started.

Comment: *"... by converting the hex to decimal ..."* that's just formatting output of the same value. I.e. `0xAA` *is* `170` and that *is* `0b10101010`, it's the same value all the time, just using different formatting to represent it by font characters. If you would want to represent 170 as amount of stones in hand, you would need to pick 170 of them. The value 170 itself is purely abstract, even writing it like this "170" is already going away from it's true abstract nature and using the decimal formatting in written form instead (which is not even perfect, for example 169.999... is the same value).